# Running Shell Command with multiple parameters shows error code 1

Tags: android, linux, shell

I am copying a kernel executable through my app in my package  folder in /data/data and trying to run it in android app using Instrumentation

I have tried `ProcessBuilder` and `Runtime.getRuntime().exec` as well both are showing Exit Code 1 and command does not run.

My command:

```
String command = "/data/data/<packageName>/e4crypt add_key -S  0x11112222333344445555666677778888 <<<  "+key;

Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        int i = proc.exitValue();
        BufferedReader stdInputs = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
        String line = "";
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = stdInputs.readLine()) != null) {
            output.append(line);
        }
```

How to format the long string? I have tried `ProcessBuilder` and `Runtime.getRuntime().exec` and `UiDevice.getInstance(getInstrumentation()).executeShellCommand()`

The first parameter is "add_key" Even when i run the executable with one parameter it shows Exitcode=1 and it does not run.  Same command works fine from command window.

I suspect the command formatting is incorrect.

Comment: Instead of using "String command", can you use command as array of Strings and initialize each element (i.e. command[0]="/data/data/<packageName>/e4crypt" , command[1]="add_key")? Also check what is error by reading proc.getErrorStream().

Comment: String[] commands = new String[2];
        commands [0] = Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/data/com.lock.gpanda.mypattern/e4crypt";
  commands [1] = " add_key";   ---->  with this I get a comma seperator between the commands.    But if I use the String command I see error - >>command = "/data/data/com.lock.gpanda.mypattern/e4crypt add_key"
process = {UNIXProcess@4631} "Process[pid=6969 ,hasExited=true, exitcode=1]"es = {UNIXProcess$ProcessPipeInputStream@4635} 
error = "java.lang.UNIXProcess$ProcessPipeInputStream@89c97bb"
is = {UNIXProcess$ProcessPipeInputStream@4643}

Comment: The paremeters are to be passed to the executable.